# SwiftUI CoreData - Store Fetch Request Data

Tags: swiftui

I am having real difficulty using Fetch Data from Core Data Entity.
All I need to do is to Fetch Data and use within my Code.
My approach technique maybe wrong hence the difficulty.
I hoped to get the Data and store into an array

I have a function which processed the data, but all I am able to do is to display the result in a view.
I would like to store the data in an Array, where I attempted to **EmptyArray.append[newElement]**
Error: Code is **dictionaryWord.append(word.englishName)** and error is **Type of expression is ambiguous without more context**

```
//Game Play
struct gamePlay: View {

    //Set CoreData environment
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(entity: Dictionary.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var dictionary: FetchedResults<Dictionary>


    //Variables for Game Play
    @State private var dictionaryWord: [String] = []
    @State private var correctAnswer = Int.random(in: 0...2)





    //Function to retrieve records from CoreData
    func processListPicture() -> some View {



    NavigationView {


        VStack {

                List(dictionary,id: \.self) { word in

                            HStack {
                                Text(word.englishName)
                                Image(word.imageName)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                Text("- Urhobo: \(word.urhoboName)")


                            }


                }//End of ForEach / List
        }


    }.navigationBarTitle(Text("English Word Translator"),displayMode: .inline)


    }//End of Function
```

Comment: I have just been doing a bit more reading and realised that the ForEach in SwiftUI is totally different from the way I used it in UIKit. It will help if some one could assist me attempting to cast my results from the retrieving of results from CoreData inito an Empty Array. My aim is to shuffle the Array and perform random output for a small game. The game I have got working, with a list of elements in a Static Array List. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you format your question a bit better? At the moment it's difficult to know where the problem is in your code.

Comment: I am sorry I am not making myself clearer. I will try once more. I have data contained within CoreData. I am able to retrieve the data, but in a List View. I need to store the result from the Fetch Request into an Array, say an empty array for example. I hope I have made myself a little clearer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you are trying to convert FetchedResults<Result> (called 'dictionary') to an array, where Result is a CoreData's entity called Dictionary.

To shuffle it, you can do:

```
let shuffledDictionaries: [Dictionary] = dictionary.shuffled()
```

If you wan conserve the original order:

```
let dictionaries: [Dictionary] = dictionary.map { $0 }
```

Or if you want any specific order:

```
let sortedDictionaries: [Dictionary] = dictionary.sorted(by: { ... })
```